# Configure nginx rewrite without breaking proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm new to nginx, and I can't seem to get a `proxy_pass` configuration to move a visitor to a subfolder without breaking the proxy.

This configuration for **proxy.com** proxies to **example.com** the way I want...

```
location /topic/ {
  proxy_pass http://example.com/topicservice/;
}
```

...but **example.com/topicservice/** itself has no HTML, only some shared files such as images.  The HTML is in subfolders.  So, with the above, if a user browses to **proxy.com/topic/subfolderA/**, or **proxy.com/topic/subfolderB/** everything works fine.

But if a user does not specify a subfolder, and just visits **proxy.com/topic/**, I want to redirect them to a default one, say **proxy.com/topic/subfolderA/**.

I've tried all kinds of embarrassing attempts at `rewrite` regexes and code from various examples online, but haven't had any luck.  The nginx documentation is way over my head.  If I get the rewrite to behave the way I want, it always seems to break the `proxy_pass`, and the subfolder HTML that is referencing content in the parent folder (../) starts looking for it at **proxy.com/topic/** instead of **example.com/topicservice/**.

But since everything works fine with the above as long as the user manually specifies the subfolder, I feel like there's got to be some (probably simple) way to do this, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Try `rewrite ^/topic/?$ /topic/subfolderA/;` outside of any location, in the `server` context.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, although I had to specify the full URL for the second argument.  I'll take it!  Thanks again.

Comment: dont forget to add a answeres status to the question